# Getting multiple queryset list of single model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model say:

```
class Abc(models.model):
    ....
    .....
```

Now When performing query(let go all the imports):

`print(Abc.objects.all())`

I am getting multiple lists of querySet:

**Output as**

`<QuerySet [<Abc: ...>, <Abc: .....> , .....]> 
<QuerySet [<Abc: ...>, <Abc: .....> , .....]>`

I have to User so I am getting 2 different **QuerySet**. How can I get all the user's querySet in single list,

**Wanted output as:**

`<QuerySet [<Abc: ...>, <Abc: .....> , .....]>, <QuerySet [<Abc: ...>, <Abc: .....> , .....]>` or in a single list 
 `<QuerySet [<Abc: ...>, <Abc: .....> , .....]>`

But from my knowledge a model should list all the querySet in a single list, why am I getting multiple lists?
[Image of my model and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peSsj.png)

Comment: `print(Abc.objects.all())` will print the only *single* queryset. In your case, there may be a chance for you may be calling it twice. You can verify that by calling it from Django Shell

Comment: Does the list_display in django Admin calls the method as many times the object is present in the list ?

Comment: No. It won't call N times

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the union function to do that.
See the document for more detail:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union